# error: unfortunately <application name> has stopped in android emulator

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-xml

I am developing login page and it shows error that unfortunately LoginC has stopped working.
logcat displays following message

```
03-31 07:24:35.896: D/AndroidRuntime(1263): Shutting down VM
03-31 07:24:35.906: W/dalvikvm(1263): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a1bba8)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): Process: com.example.loginc, PID: 1263
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginc/com.example.loginc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.example.loginc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-31 07:24:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     private EditText  username=null;
     private EditText  password=null;
     private TextView attempts;
     private Button login;
     int counter = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    }

    public void login(View view){
          if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
          password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }    
       else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);   
          counter--;
          attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
          if(counter==0){
             login.setEnabled(false);
          }

       }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Above is the code written in mainactivity.java file

and below details are written in fragment_main.xml file

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.loginc.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
  android:text="@string/hello_world"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
  android:text="@string/username"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
  android:ems="10"
  android:inputType="text" >

  <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
  android:text="@string/password"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
  android:ems="10"
  android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
  android:onClick="login"
  android:text="@string/Login" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView4"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
  android:text="@string/attempts"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView5"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
  android:text="TextView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your Java code along with your layout XML.

Comment: Post your MainActivity.java

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml too.

Comment: The error log tells you where the error is: MainActivity.java class line 35. Have a look at the this line first.

Comment: move all your views to fragment. views belong to the fragment

Comment: editText1 is not in `activity_main.xml` then that will return NPE

Answer (score 0):

A Null PointerException means that you tried to do an operation on a value that was set to `null` (Basically not initialized). You can think of a value without a setting like an unprogrammed credit card, you can carry it around, but if you try to use it it won't work. So, what value could still be null in your `onCreate` function?

I strongly suspect that line 35 is this one, and if it's not, then this answer won't apply. Your error is on line 35, or at least related to that:

```
attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
```

I'm assuming that `attempts` is somehow null. Where is this set?

```
attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
```

Okay, so let's look at the documentation for [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

> public View findViewById (int id)
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that
>   was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
>
> Returns: The view if found or null otherwise.

So if the view couldn't be found somehow, then attempts could be null. How can we tell if it's actually null? Let's try a log statement, include this right after the `findViewById`

```
Log.v("Main","attempts="+attempts);
```

Okay, let's assume it is actually the null value. Then what do we do? Well, according to the docs, that means it wasn't found. Well, let's look at the setContentView statement:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Okay, so your view should be in `activity_main.xml`. I see that it is in your code, but you called the file `fragment_main.xml`. Bottom line is, you're trying to get the `attempts` value from the wrong XML file. Okay, so what are the solutions here?

1. Your best bet is to manage all of this in the fragment that lays out `fragment_main.xml`. This might require a bit of work, but in the end will give you the best performance.
2. If you are certain you are never going to want to use fragments (No tablet support, poor screen rotation performance, and other consequences might follow), then you could just substitute `R.layout.fragment_main` in your `setContentView`.

In any case, choose one of these, and your problem should go away.

If you choose the first, you will need to put the code inside the `onCreateView`, and reference the via the root view (What onCreateView returns). Something like `view.findViewById`.

Comment: I got it what you are trying to say.. if i choose 1st option then what changes will be need?

Comment: Okay...can you please tell me difference between fragment_main.xml and activity_main.xml. exactly what both the files are for?

Answer (score 0):

move these to `onCreateView`

```
 username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

as those id(s) are in `fragment_main.xml` , not in `activity_main.xml`, thus the NPE.

Also, use `rootView.findViewById` there.